# How can I convert SQL to lambda expressions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

In my database, I created the tables structure as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE Course 
(
    Course_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    Stu_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Mobile varchar(255),
    Age int,
    Course_ID int,
    FOREIGN KEY (Course_ID) REFERENCES Course(Course_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Subject  
(
    Sub_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Teacher 
(
    Teach_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Mobile varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Course_Subject 
(
    CouSub_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Course_ID int,
    Sub_ID int,
    FOREIGN KEY (Course_ID) REFERENCES Course(Course_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Sub_ID) REFERENCES Subject(Sub_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Teacher_Subject 
(
    TeachSub_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Teach_ID int,
    Sub_ID int,
    FOREIGN KEY (Teach_ID) REFERENCES Teacher(Teach_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Sub_ID) REFERENCES Subject(Sub_ID)
);
```

Now my problem is I need to retrieve students data who learned from some teacher, which means need to retrieve some teacher's students who learned from his/her. To accomplish my requirement. I write this SQL query.

```
select 
    s.*
from 
    tbl_student s
inner join 
    Course_Subject tcs on s.Course_Id = tcs.Course_Id
inner join 
    Teacher_Subject tst on tst.Sub_ID = tcs.Sub_ID
inner join 
    Teacher t on t.Teach_ID = tst.Teach_ID
where 
    t.Teach_ID = @SomeTeacherId
```

Now I need to convert this query to a lambda expression or Linq. How can I do it? Please help me. Have any possible way to generate this using Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't use `join`. Create navigation properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use [EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first) to generate object mapping to your tables. And use LINQ to rewrite your query with a slightly different syntax:

```
var result = from students in tbl_student
             join subjects in Course_Subject on students.Course_Id == subjects.Course_Id
             join ts in Teacher_Subject on subjects.Sub_ID == ts.Sub_ID
             join teachers in Teacher on teachers.Teach_ID == ts.Teach_ID
             where teachers.Teach_ID == "your_value"
             select students;
```

Not sure it's an absolutely correct query, but I hope you'll get the main idea.

Answer (score 2):

> **Have any possible way to generate this using Visual Studio.?**

Yes, you can do this using [Linq-to-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins#example---inner-join-by-using-grouped-join)

for your query, this might be appropriated

```
var students = from student in db.Students
            join tcs in db.CourseSubjects on student.CourseId equals tcs.CourseId
            join tst in db.TeacherSubjects on tcs.SubId equals tst.SubId
            join t in db.Teachers on tst.TeachId equals t.TeachId
            where t.TeachId == someTeacherId
            select student;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda:

```
Students
.Where(x=> x.Course.Course_Subjects
        .Any(y => y.Subject.Teacher_Subjects
                .Any(z => z.Teach_ID == someTeacherId)
        )
)
.Select(x => x)
```